# QGIS: Successful query, but no result

Tags: error, quickosm

I ran Quick OSM in QGIS 3.30.1 :

- `'Key'` to `'building'`
- `'LayerExtent'` to `'dem'`

and the following message appears :

> Successful query, but no result.

I searched the place where it has many buildings.

Comment: Can you give the Coordinate Reference System of your `'dem'` layer please ?

Comment: Without more details, we can't answer you. Share logs from QGIS, the comic strip bubble in the bottom right corner, then in "QuickOSM" tab.